# Apache tomcat installation

Tags: tomcat

I just installed apache tomcat 6.0 32-bit/64-bit Windows installer for Tomcat. Its bin file contains only 4 files: bootstrap.jar, Tomcat6.exe, Tomcat6w.exe, tomcat-juli.exe and does not contain startup.bat file.

What can I do to start it?

Answer (score 0):

It's been installed as a Windows service, so you have a couple of options:

1. Start it manually from Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.
2. Start it from the command line: `net start {your service name}`

If you didn't switch it off during the installation configuration process, the "Monitor Tomcat" tool will also be available in your system tray. It has two commands: Start and Stop.